# python - Issue in processing files with big size

Tags: python, file-processing

Basically, I wanted to create a Python script for my daily tasks wherein i wanted to compare two file with any size & wanted to generated 2 new files having matching records & non-matching records from both file.

I have written below python script & found it's working properly for file size having few records.

But when i am executing same script with files with 200,000 and 500,000 records then resulting file getting generated is not giving valid output.

So, can you check below script and help to identify issue in it causing wrong output...?

Thanks in advance.

```
from sys import argv

script, filePathName1, filePathName2  = argv

def FileDifference(filePathName1, filePathName2):
    fileObject1 = open(filePathName1,'r')
    fileObject2 = open(filePathName2,'r')
    newFilePathName1 = filePathName1 + ' - NonMatchingRecords.txt'
    newFilePathName2 = filePathName1 + ' - MatchingRecords.txt'
    newFileObject1 = open(newFilePathName1,'a')
    newFileObject2 = open(newFilePathName2,'a')
    file1 = fileObject1.readlines()
    file2 = fileObject2.readlines()
    Differece = [ diff for diff in file1 if diff not in file2 ]
    for i in range(0,len(Differece)):
        newFileObject1.write(Differece[i])

    Matching = [ match for match in file1 if match in file2 ]
    for j in range(0,len(Matching)):
        newFileObject2.write(Matching[j])
    fileObject1.close()
    fileObject2.close()
    newFileObject1.close()
    newFileObject2.close()

FileDifference(filePathName1, filePathName2)
```

Edit-1 : Pls note that above program executes without any error. Its just that output is incorrect and program takes much longer time to get over large file.

Comment: what is the error or how you can say it's invalid output. can u give some examples

Comment: I'd say that you'd have to turn `file2` into a `set` or lookup time will be horrible with a list. Actually, create sets out of both line lists and perform intersection / difference using `set` methods. It'll be much faster.

Comment: I think you mean: "it never ends / it runs forever", right?

Comment: Nope, program runs without any error but execution time is quite long & output is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a wild guess and assume that "no valid output" means: "runs forever and does nothing useful".

Which would be logical because of your list comprehensions:

```
    Differece = [ diff for diff in file1 if diff not in file2 ]
    for i in range(0,len(Differece)):
        newFileObject1.write(Differece[i])

Matching = [ match for match in file1 if match in file2 ]
for i in range(0,len(Matching)):
    newFileObject2.write(Matching[i])
```

They perform `O(n)` lookup, which is okay on a small number of lines but never ends if, say `len(file1) == 100000` and so is `file2`. You then perform 100000*100000 iterations => 10**10 => forever.

Fix is simple: create `sets` and use `intersection` & `difference`, much faster.

```
    file1 = set(fileObject1.readlines())
    file2 = set(fileObject2.readlines())
    difference = file1 - file2
    for i in difference:
        newFileObject1.write(i)

matching = file1 & file2
for i in matching:
    newFileObject2.write(matching)
```

Comment: Hi Jean-François Fabre & All,

Thanks for above comment.

Actually, I found an issue in my original files itself which i was processing. I found that records in file was having lots of blank space which changed records & that didnt match with record in other file. 

I removed those blank spaces & now getting proper & valid output.

Also, script execution completes within second after changes suggested by you.